# Downloading file from the right Apache Mirror with wget

Tags: url, download

To use a specific example, I want to download the binary release of Hadoop 2.7.2. The [web site](http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html) points to http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.2/hadoop-2.7.2.tar.gz which then points to the closest mirror by location. For me that is http://xenia.sote.hu/ftp/mirrors/www.apache.org/hadoop/core/hadoop-2.7.2/hadoop-2.7.2.tar.gz.

I want to actually download this in a shell script (a Dockerfile to be specific). I would prefer to use a location-agnostic URL for the download so that if someone runs the script on the other end of the world, they would not use the same mirror.

Is there a URL I could use with `wget` or `curl` that dynamically redirects to the closest mirror? What would that URL be for this specific file?

Comment: Probably relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21534797

Comment: Ah, thanks! This could even be closed as a duplicate then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the closest Apache Software Foundation mirror programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21534797/finding-the-closest-apache-software-foundation-mirror-programatically)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [source code of closer.lua](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/infrastructure/site/trunk/content/dyn/closer.lua) actually states that the `action` and `filename` query parameters may be used to produce a redirect to the requested file on the automatically chosen mirror instead of the usual HTML mirror selection page.

So you can download the files directly via this URL: https://www.apache.org/dyn/mirrors/mirrors.cgi?action=download&filename=hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.2/hadoop-2.7.2.tar.gz:

```
GET /dyn/mirrors/mirrors.cgi?action=download&filename=hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.2/hadoop-2.7.2.tar.gz HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: www.apache.org



HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 13 Mar 2017 18:08:00 GMT
Expires: Mon, 13 Mar 2017 19:08:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=30, max=100
Location: http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/ftp.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.2/hadoop-2.7.2.tar.gz
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
```

Comment: The trick is to use quotation marks around the url with wget: `wget --trust-server-names "https://www.apache.org/dyn/mirrors/mirrors.cgi?action=download&filename=hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.2/hadoop-2.7.2.tar.gz"`

Comment: You start by referring to the source code of `closer.lua`, but then your example uses `mirrors.cgi`. Are they supposed to be the same thing?

Comment: `mirrors.cgi` actually renders `closer.lua` and sends the rendered content to the client.

Comment: I initially tried the link in the answer ([hadoop-2.7.2](https://www.apache.org/dyn/mirrors/mirrors.cgi?action=download&filename=hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.2/hadoop-2.7.2.tar.gz)) and it did not work. Then realized that version is no longer hosted. Remember to use the latest version (at the time of writing, [2.7.7](https://www.apache.org/dyn/mirrors/mirrors.cgi?action=download&filename=hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.7/hadoop-2.7.7.tar.gz)) and it will work.