# Finding an active Hadoop mirror

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I'm currently using a setup script that launches EC2 instances and installs Hadoop/Spark from the binaries.

The author currently has hardcoded a mirror from [this](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.8.4/hadoop-2.8.4.tar.gz) list, but any mirror could change/be removed at any point.

Is there a more "principled" way to get mirrors/download locations for Apache projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42770603/2706419)

> wget --trust-server-names  "https://www.apache.org/dyn/mirrors/mirrors.cgi?action=download&filename=hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.2/hadoop-2.7.2.tar.gz"